# Flutter App Counting Google Analytics Events TWICE

Tags: flutter, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I am logging some predefined event and custom events on my flutter app using Google Analytics through the below way:

```
 FirebaseAnalytics.instance.logEvent(
          name: "select_content",
          parameters: {
            "content_type": "BusinessProfile",
            "item_id": selectedbusinessprofileid,
            "user_id": globaluserid,
            "Access_Method": "Ad",
            "Ad_Method": "CategoriesBoard",
            "Gender": globalusergender,
            "City": globaluserdefaultcity,
          },
        );

         FirebaseAnalytics.instance.logEvent(
    name: "New_Business_Profile",
    parameters: {
      "category": bpaddselectedcategory,
      "Gender": globalusergender,
      "City": globaluserdefaultcity,
    },
  );
```

the problem is that each event is logged TWICE in google analytics dashboard, in both debug view and production view. the behavior is for both predefined events like "select_content" and any other customer event I create like "New_Business_Profile".

I did some search, some mentioned I need to remove the events I've created from Google Analytics Admin. I did and delete it, the events are still counting twice like this.

[image: Like This]

any idea what is the reason of this problem or how can I solve it?

Edit: Solved in Debug mode, Removing the events from Google Analytics Admin solved the issue in Debug mode but it took around two hours to be corrected.
will check the production mode in 24 hours and report if solved too.

Edit: Worked fine on live too.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use Dart Debugger and breakpoints. Most likely your code is invoked more than once.

Comment: Hello, thanks. No, I checked that, only the event is logged twice but the code is correct. I just edited the question as it seems removing the events from the admin dashboard solved the issue.

Comment: Then, please, send your full code. I still think that that you invoke that twice.